# "No Value given for one or more required parameters"

Tags: c#

```
string Category = comboBox1.Text;
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=C:\\Users\\admin\\Documents\\INV.xlsx; Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0\"";
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
string sql = "SELECT * FROM [RAW DATA$] WHERE [Category: Name] = @Category";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@num", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Category;
OleDbDataAdapter dataadapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection);
```

Comment: A standard issue with Access (jet oledb) is that it interprets everything it doesn't know as a parameter, so make sure you actuablle have a column named "Category: Name", and a table named "RAW DATA$".

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 1):

OleDbCommand doesn't support named parameters, take a look at [msdn documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx)

change `CommandText` like this:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM [RAW DATA$] WHERE [Category: Name] = ?";
```

Comment: string sql = "SELECT * FROM [RAW DATA$] WHERE [Category: Name] = ?";
               I did change my code but still throwing the same error...